# jqgrid - change to custom sorting icos

Tags: sorting, jqgrid, icons

i am using jqgrid to present a grid ,
i whould like to custom the sorting icons ,
we have a CMS and the content (include the arrows ) is controled by our clients. 
however i don't have a problem doing it either by CSS or by code(js). 
currently i see fixed arrows that are presented ,and the only thing i could custom is the possion and the apperance (vertical /horizinal) .

my needs : 
1.sperate icons for asc and desc(that will be coustom images).
2.present one icon each click (tougle between the icons )

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The grid receives the icons from the jQuery UI Theme that your page is using. So you might be able to override the grid's CSS classes to achieve your solution. The icons used for sorting have the classes `ui-icon-triangle-1-n` and `ui-icon-triangle-1-s`.

Comment: thans,can you please show an example hoe to do it ? lets say i want to use diffent arrows ? overide the exsisting arrows with my custom arrows ,or select diffrent arrows from the grid defulats ,and present only 1 relevant arrow instead of 2 as the defulat.